# WSL Ubuntu creates duplicate files of some formats if we open git dir in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

I am running ubuntu 22 on windows wsl, when i open wsl file in vscode it creates duplicate files with weird extension has encoded string. like in image bastion.pub. sometimes i notice this happens to .txt file too. is there is issue opening this git directory from wsl ubuntu to vscode in windows? anyone had such issue? if you solved how did you?

Comment: This is not a feature of WSL or VSCode - you have something else in your setup causing this.

Comment: This might be caused by a cloud syncing service such as Dropbox if you're using one.  If so, you shouldn't use such a tool with Git repositories, because it can corrupt them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix the issue by using wsl extension in vscode, its actually happens git try to re-index if we open outside wsl env.